# .preventDefault jQuery won't execute on page, but will execute when typed in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, materialize

my code is a simple click event `e.preventDefault` command for a hamburger menu. The file loads in the browser, but the preventDefault won't work.

When I copy and paste the code into Chrome's console, the click event works just find.  What am I missing?

```
$(function(){
  console.log('dashboard jquery loaded');
  $(".button-collapse").click(function(e){
    console.log('button pressed');
    e.preventDefault();
  });


});
```

App is built in Angular 1, I am using materializeeCSS for the hamburger menu

Comment: Doesn't work there either, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.  I am using AngularJS (and new to it) and I was putting the jQuery in its own JS file, when I should have been putting the jQuery code in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is, `.button-collapse` is a class used by bootstarp. Here you're trying to bind a `click` event to a bootstarp element which has it's own click listner in `bootstrap.js`. That's the reason it might not work.

Try changing the class name of the button.